# Android: ParseQueryAdapter to query multiple classes

Tags: android, parse-platform

This is my first question asked and hopefully someone can help me.  I have looked around and nothing on this subject has helped me in my situation yet which is why I resorted to posting a request for help.

I have a parse.com database setup with the following *Classes*:

**Users**, **Followers**, and **Items**.

**Followers** contains two columns *follower* and *following* to keep track of which user is following which user.

**Items** contains an *author* column which is a pointer to a **User** object.

My goal is to make a query for a ParseQueryAdapter that will return **Items** objects.  The path that I have to **Items** right now is to query the **Followers** class to get a list of *users* that the current user is following.  Then use those user objects as pointers  query the **Items** class for items the followed user has created.

Here is a diagram:

```
Followers

follower following
-------  ---------
UserA    UserB
UserB    UserC
UserB    UserA


Items

author column1 column2
------ ------- -------
UserA  foo     bar
UserA  foo2    bar2
UserB  blah    blah
UserC  blah    blah
```

Based on the above database structure let's assume that currentUser is UserB.  If UserB queries the Follower table he will retrieve his follower list (UserC and UserA) and then I would like to query to go out and retrieve all of the Items created by those that UserB follows (which should return 3 results based on the above structure).  Based on my limited understanding of how parse.com works here is what I have tried:

```
public class ItemListItemAdapter extends ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject>{

public ItemListItemAdapter(Context context) {
    super(context, new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject>() {
        public ParseQuery<ParseObject> create() {

            ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

            ParseQuery<ParseObject> followerQuery = new ParseQuery("Followers");
            followerQuery.whereEqualTo("follower", currentUser);

            ParseQuery<ParseObject> itemQuery = new ParseQuery("Items");
            itemQuery.whereMatchesQuery("author", followerQuery);

            return itemQuery;

        }
    });
}
```

As I understand it I am first creating a query that will get the followers that *currentUser* is following.  Then I should have a list of **User** objects that can be used to query the **Items** class where the **User** object matches the followers so that I can populate my ListView item with the right data from that **Item** object but this query returns zero results.

So either I am modeling everything wrong or I am misunderstanding how relationships work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

If I remove the *itemQuery* and just return the *followerQuery* then it works - the problem is with the inner query when I try to combine the two (or it could be me complicating my life with the data structure in the database so I'm also open to suggestions on restructuring).

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was to not use `whereMatchesQuery()` but `whereMatchesKeyInQuery()` instead.

here is an example using `whereMatchesKeyInQuery()` (that is not necessarily specific to this question but demonstrating the use of `whereMatchesKeyInQuery` by request in the comments):

```
ParseQuery followerQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("Followers");
followerQuery.whereEqualTo("following", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
userQuery.whereMatchesKeyInQuery("objectId", "followerId", followerQuery);
```

So the parameters would be:

```
query1.whereMatchesKeyInQuery("key_value_in_query1", "key_value_to_match_in_query2", query2);
```

Comment: If i want the data from Followers and Items class both then what i do for that. This code only return data from items class

Comment: what is the syntax like for the whereMatchesKeyInQuery?  I am having a heck of a time getting this to work with a similar situation.

Comment: @JenniferS I updated my answer at your request - let me know if you need any more assistance.

Comment: Thanks, @MaxWorg.  Here's my issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30333251/parsequeryadapter-key-match-empty-android