# ParseQueryAdapter key match empty Android

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-parsequeryadapter

I have three parse subclasses: Recipe, Ingredient, and RecipeIngredient. RecipeIngredient has a pointer to a Recipe, and a pointer to an Ingredient.

When I am trying to create a QueryFactory to get all the ingredients for a recipe. I am trying to do this with whereMatchesKeyInQuery, but the objectIds aren't matching.  From the docs, it appears that this should be legal.  What am I missing?

```
 public MeatIngredientListAdapter(Context context, final String recipeName) {
    super(context, new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<Ingredient>() {
        public ParseQuery<Ingredient> create() {

            ParseQuery<Ingredient> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Ingredient.class);
            query.whereEqualTo("isMeatOrFat", true);

            ParseQuery<RecipeIngredient> riQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery(RecipeIngredient.class);
            riQuery.whereEqualTo("recipeName", recipeName);
            riQuery.include("ingredient");
            riQuery.whereEqualTo("isMeatOrFat", true);

            query.whereMatchesKeyInQuery("objectId", "ingredient.objectId", riQuery);

            return query;
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of the sub query? Is not clear to me what the Recipe ingredient should do to the result of Ingredients returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case the use of `whereMatchesKeyInQuery` is overkill.  I might not have enough information to make this call about your app but is seems that you would be able to cut out the need for `RecipeIngredient` all together if you just create a `Relation` of the `Ingredient` class inside the `Recipe` class.  This will simplify your queries and make your app more scalable and give you features (explained below).  If you had a data structure like this:

```
Recipe Class
 - Name (String)
 - ingredients (Relation of the Ingredient class)

Ingredient Class
 - <Columns to describe the ingredient that you already have in place>
```

Now you can store one recipe that "points" (using relations) to many ingredients.

So an example entry might look like this:

```
Recipe
 Name
  PB&J
 ingredients
  Peanut Butter //this is a relation to the Peanut Butter Ingredient object
  Jelly         //this is a relation to the Jelly Ingredient object

Ingredient
 Name
  Peanut Butter
 Calories
  ...
 Cost
  ...
```

And here in code we add the data to the classes:

```
ParseObject ingredient1 = new ParseObject(Ingredient.class);
ingredient1.put("Name", "Peanut Butter");

ParseObject ingredient2 = new ParseObject(Ingredient.class);
ingredient1.put("Name", "Jelly");


ParseObject recipe = new ParseObject("Recipe");
recipe.put("Name", "PB&J");

ParseRelation<ParseObject> relation = recipe.getRelation("ingredients");
relation.add(ingredient1);
relation.add(ingredient2);

recipe.saveInBackground();
```

The magic behind this setup is that we can now specify a recipe by name and get all ingredients like you wanted but we can also retrieve all recipes that have certain ingredient(s) in them (this is the beauty of a many-to-many relationship) and on top of that it simplifies your queries.

Now for the original query you wanted with this new setup:

```
ParseObject recipe = ...; // "PB&J" Recipe object.

ParseRelation relation = recipe.getRelation("ingredients");

// generate a query based on that relation
ParseQuery query = relation.getQuery();
```

`query` will hold all of the ingredients for the `recipe` object when the query is executed.

Now suppose you want to create a query where you get all of the recipes that contain a certain ingredient:

```
ParseObject ingredient = ...

ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Recipe");

query.whereEqualTo("ingredients", ingredient); //use whereContainedIn for multiple ingredients
```

`query` will contain all Recipe objects that have the specified ingredient in their `ingredients` relation column when the query is executed.

I hope this helped you.  Please let me know if I severely misunderstood the structure of your app - if so I will revise my answer if you give me new information but honestly I think the "middle man" `RecipeIngredient` is forcing you to complicate your app.

Comment: Thanks for this, @MaxWorg.  I've been trying to figure out the best way to structure the data, and to get the adapters to work. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to put things in subclasses. Sometimes the documentation examples are a bit too simple for me to really understand the best way to do something.

Comment: I have felt your pain :D The documentation in my opinion has been rather incomplete (and in some cases I have found that the documentation and examples are outdated which makes them incorrect) and I have been left on my own to figure things out many times.  Let me know if I can be of any more assistance.

Comment: this is slick!  But now I am trying to add steps to the recipe as another Relation, and the saving isn't working.  Are you stuck with only one relation per object??